# Sorting through findContours()'s return value; contours list

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having issues sorting contours how I want them to be sorted.

I have two columns and K(variable) rows in an image that I'm trying to draw contours and then crop out. I can do this fine but I need them to get returned in a specific order.

I'm halfway there since I managed to sort them as such;
1st column gets returned first in the contours list then when it's done it goes to the second column and goes through all its rows as well.

These are the lines of code that are sorting the list:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_value, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours.sort(key=lambda c: np.min(c[:, :, 0]))
contours.reverse()
```

I need to get a return value of: [[Column1, row1], [Column2, row1], ....] and as such.

Here's a more specific example.

[image]

Right now it's being stored like the following:

[image]

What should I change in that sort instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445901/15019732).

It's working like magic make sure to upvote them and show gratitude to the original answer please.

```
def get_contour_precedence(contour, cols):
    origin = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return origin[1] * cols + origin[0]


contours.sort(key=lambda x:get_contour_precedence(x, image.shape[1]))
```

A well written explanation can be found in the original answer but the code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you can do is simply get all contours and then find all the polygons that can be formed with them. You can remove the larger ones as you don't need contour of entire table or entire row/column. Once you filter those out you will be remaining with the small ones i.e. cells. Then you can extract them easily and index them according to their centorid. Using those centorid you will know the position of each and can put them anywhere according to your choice.

Comment: Found the answer you may check below. Thanks for the suggestion.