# Opencv contour sorting

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm new to python and Opencv. I'm working on a project to build an app to recognize handwritings in local language. One of the critical part of it to find the order of the words and character. So far manage to segment the words and letters. The problem is contours are not in the order. I followed this question [Python opencv sorting contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403183/python-opencv-sorting-contours/39445901?noredirect=1#comment120568727_39445901) and got a pretty good result. Still some horizontal contours are not in the order. How can I fix this?

```
def image_process(self):
    image = cv2.imread(self.img)

    #grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (8,8))
    bg=cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, se)
    out_gray=cv2.divide(gray, bg, scale=255)
    out_binary=cv2.threshold(out_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1]

    #binary
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(out_binary,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # opening
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    #dilation 40 for segmenting words 15 for letters
    kernel = np.ones(5,40), np.uint8)

    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=1)

    #find contours
    # ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    contours, h = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours.sort(key=lambda x:get_contour_precedence(x, img_dilation.shape[0]))

    for i, ctr in enumerate(contours):

        # Get bounding box
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

        M = cv2.moments(ctr)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        
        cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (cX - 20, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 0), 2)


        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(90,0,255),2)



def get_contour_precedence(contour, cols):
    tolerance_factor = 61
    origin = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return ((origin[1] // tolerance_factor) * tolerance_factor) * cols + origin[0]
```

[image: Output is like this:]

[image: Original Image]

Comment: Can you also post the image of the handwriting sample without the bounding rectangles and the  `#number` annotations, so that we can play around and try some things for ourselves?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66946804/python-sorting-items-from-top-left-to-bottom-right-with-opencv/67008153?r=SearchResults#67008153

Comment: Hi @BioGeek, I add the original Image

Answer (score 2):

I have expanded on the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67008153/50065) from [Ann Zen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13552470/ann-zen).

There are two variables that you will have to tweak:

- `threshold`: contours with an area below this threshold will be discarded
- `row_amt`: the number of rows that there are in your image

The concept that [Ann Zen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13552470/ann-zen) used is to divide the image into `n` segments along the y axis, forming `n` rows. For each segment of the image, find every shape that has its center in that segment. Finally, order the shapes in each segment by their x coordinate.

1. Import the necessary libraries. I have a `DEBUG` flag that will show some extra features which can help during debugging.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

DEBUG = False
```

2. Define a function that will take in an image input and return the image processed to something that will allow python to later retrieve their contours:

```
def process_img(image):
    # grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8, 8))
    bg = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, se)
    out_gray = cv2.divide(gray, bg, scale=255)
    out_binary = cv2.threshold(out_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # binary
    (ret, thresh) = cv2.threshold(out_binary, 127, 255,
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    # opening
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    # dilation 40 for segmenting words 15 for letters
    kernel = np.ones((5, 40), np.uint8)

    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_dilation
```

3. Define a function that will return the center of a contour:

```
def get_centeroid(cnt):
    length = len(cnt)
    sum_x = np.sum(cnt[..., 0])
    sum_y = np.sum(cnt[..., 1])
    return int(sum_x / length), int(sum_y / length)
```

4. Define a function that returns all the contours of which the area is above a threshold:

```
def get_contours(processed_img, threshold):
    (contours, hierarchies) = cv2.findContours(processed_img,
            cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    return [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > threshold]
```

5. Define a function that will take in a list of contours and return the center points of the shapes found in the image:

```
def get_centers(contours):
    return [get_centeroid(cnt) for cnt in contours]
```

6. Define a function that will find the upper and lower bound along the y axis of the contours. Based on the amount of rows you provide, it splits the area between these bounds in `amt_row` rows of height `row_h`.

```
def get_bounds(contours, img, row_amt):
    min_y = img.shape[0]
    max_y = 0
    for ctr in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
        if y < min_y:
            min_y = y
        if y + h > max_y:
            max_y = y + h

    row_h = (max_y - min_y) / row_amt

    if DEBUG:
        line_thickness = 2
        x1 = 0
        x2 = img.shape[1]
        for i in range(row_amt + 1):
            y1 = y2 = int(min_y + row_h * i)
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0),
                     thickness=line_thickness)
    return (min_y, max_y, row_h)
```

7. Define a function that will take in an image array, `img`, the number of segments for the image, `row_amt`, and a `threshold`. Contours with an area below this threshold will be discarded. It will return `row_amt` OrderedDicts. Each OrderedDict contains as keys the centers of its corresponding row, sorted by their x coordinates and the value for each key is its corresponding contour.

```
def get_rows(img, row_amt, threshold):
    processed_img = process_img(img)
    contours = get_contours(processed_img, threshold)
    centers = get_centers(contours)
    centers_to_contours = dict(zip(centers, contours))
    centers = np.array(centers)
    min_y, max_y, row_h = get_bounds(contours, img, row_amt)

    for i in range(row_amt):
        f = centers[:, 1] - min_y - row_h * i
        a = centers[(f < row_h) & (f > 0)]
        c = a[a.argsort(0)[:, 0]]
        od = OrderedDict()
        for center in map(tuple, c):
            od[center] = centers_to_contours[center]
        yield od
```

8. Read in the image, loop over the rows and in each row loop over the centers/contours and draw the rectangles and numbers.

```
img = cv2.imread('RrU0o.jpg')

count = 0
for row in get_rows(img, row_amt=7, threshold=1330):
    if DEBUG:
        centerpoints = np.array(list(row.keys()))
        cv2.polylines(img, [centerpoints], False, (255, 0, 255), 2)

    for ((x, y), ctr) in row.items():
        count += 1
        if DEBUG:
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 10, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(img, f'#{count}', (x - 10, y + 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 0), 2)

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)
```

9. Finally, show the image:

```
cv2.imshow("Final", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

Result:

[image]

Result with `DEBUG = True`.

- Green horizontal lines show the segments
- Red dots show the center of the contours
- Pink line connects the centers in a segment in order

[image]

Altogether:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from collections import OrderedDict

DEBUG = False


def process_img(image):

    # grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8, 8))
    bg = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, se)
    out_gray = cv2.divide(gray, bg, scale=255)
    out_binary = cv2.threshold(out_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # binary
    (ret, thresh) = cv2.threshold(out_binary, 127, 255,
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # opening
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    # dilation 40 for segmenting words 15 for letters
    kernel = np.ones((5, 40), np.uint8)

    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_dilation

def get_centeroid(cnt):
    length = len(cnt)
    sum_x = np.sum(cnt[..., 0])
    sum_y = np.sum(cnt[..., 1])
    return (int(sum_x / length), int(sum_y / length))


def get_contours(processed_img, threshold):
    (contours, hierarchies) = cv2.findContours(processed_img,
            cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    return [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > threshold]


def get_centers(contours):
    return [get_centeroid(cnt) for cnt in contours]


def get_bounds(contours, img, row_amt):
    min_y = img.shape[0]
    max_y = 0
    for ctr in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
        if y < min_y:
            min_y = y
        if y + h > max_y:
            max_y = y + h

    row_h = (max_y - min_y) / row_amt

    if DEBUG:
        line_thickness = 2
        x1 = 0
        x2 = img.shape[1]
        for i in range(row_amt + 1):
            y1 = y2 = int(min_y + row_h * i)
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0),
                     thickness=line_thickness)
    return (min_y, max_y, row_h)


def get_rows(img, row_amt, threshold):
    processed_img = process_img(img)
    contours = get_contours(processed_img, threshold)
    centers = get_centers(contours)
    centers_to_contours = dict(zip(centers, contours))
    centers = np.array(centers)
    (min_y, max_y, row_h) = get_bounds(contours, img, row_amt)

    for i in range(row_amt):
        f = centers[:, 1] - min_y - row_h * i
        a = centers[(f < row_h) & (f > 0)]
        c = a[a.argsort(0)[:, 0]]
        od = OrderedDict()
        for center in map(tuple, c):
            od[center] = centers_to_contours[center]
        yield od


img = cv2.imread('RrU0o.jpg')

count = 0
for row in get_rows(img, row_amt=7, threshold=1330):
    if DEBUG:
        centerpoints = np.array(list(row.keys()))
        cv2.polylines(img, [centerpoints], False, (255, 0, 255), 2)

    for ((x, y), ctr) in row.items():
        count += 1
        if DEBUG:
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 10, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(img, f'#{count}', (x - 10, y + 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 0), 2)

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Final", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is sorting the detected words according to reading direction.

The problem consists of 2 parts:

1. Cluster (group) words into lines and sort them from top to bottom
2. Then, for each line, sort words from left to right

Part (2) is simple: take the x-center (x+w/2) of a word and then sort words in a line according to the x-center position.

Part (1) is a bit trickier: we have to group words into lines first. For this, we have to measure how close two words are.
We could e.g. project the bounding boxes of two words onto the y-axis, and then have a look how much they overlap (Jaccard metric).
The more they overlap, the "closer" they are.
We can then create a matrix containing the pairwise distances between words.
That might sound complicated, but it enables us to use some standard clustering algorithm like DBSCAN to do the hard work for us.
Each cluster corresponds to a line. We only have to sort the lines from top to bottom, and then sort each line from left to right which was task (1).

For code see function [sort_multiline](https://github.com/githubharald/WordDetector/blob/d9efbfd5a26c2ea2c03894593923015e7c6e0999/word_detector/__init__.py#L135) in the word_detector package. Here is an example output from the described method:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `get_contour_precedence()` method to get how far the object from origin `(0,0)`.

```
origin[1] = y axis
origin[0] = x axis
```

Here I have suggestion to make it also count the distance from x axis

Change this line

```
contours.sort(key=lambda x:get_contour_precedence(x, img_dilation.shape[0], img_dilation.shape[1]))
```

```
def get_contour_precedence(contour, cols, rows):
    tolerance_factor = 61
    origin = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return (origin[1]/tolerance_factor) * (cols / tolerance_factor) + (origin[0]/tolerance_factor) * (rows / tolerance_factor)
```

I modify your return a bit.

Comment: Hi @M Razif Rizqullah, Thanks for the reply but its not working.