# Sorting YOLO output for layout detection as natural reading order

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, yolo

I am following this question:
[Python opencv sorting contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403183/python-opencv-sorting-contours)

Basically my objective is, to make a Yolo layout detector of any kind pdf document, than it would be extracted as it is shown on the original page as txt files.

This is the example of the Yolo output and displayed on the page

1. First example

[first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqb34.png)

and this is the Yolo predictions output:

```
[
        {
          "xmin":103.2696609497,
          "ymin":58.3476371765,
          "xmax":499.8019104004,
          "ymax":206.1468200684,
          "confidence":0.8600681424,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":69.1876602173,
          "ymin":219.2121582031,
          "xmax":287.9017028809,
          "ymax":770.752746582,
          "confidence":0.8981021643,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":294.2664489746,
          "ymin":213.9664001465,
          "xmax":531.8371582031,
          "ymax":781.6404418945,
          "confidence":0.8986129761,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":79.8882904053,
          "ymin":779.7505493164,
          "xmax":504.9499816895,
          "ymax":818.9318237305,
          "confidence":0.6452015638,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        }
      ]
```

2. Second Exmple

[second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFpf.png)

and this is the Yolo predictions output:

```
[
        {
          "xmin":55.7774848938,
          "ymin":62.6263313293,
          "xmax":304.7996520996,
          "ymax":290.942779541,
          "confidence":0.8734897971,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":57.6998138428,
          "ymin":481.4093933105,
          "xmax":301.9298706055,
          "ymax":762.4769897461,
          "confidence":0.8662955165,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":68.3779830933,
          "ymin":310.360534668,
          "xmax":287.8137512207,
          "ymax":468.7124023438,
          "confidence":0.7535428405,
          "class":0,
          "name":"chart"
        },
        {
          "xmin":302.0565795898,
          "ymin":47.7406311035,
          "xmax":530.778503418,
          "ymax":783.8140869141,
          "confidence":0.8693569899,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        }
      ]
```

3. Third Example

[third example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcabg.png)

and this is the Yolo predictions output:

```
[
        {
          "xmin":292.6344299316,
          "ymin":38.8345985413,
          "xmax":544.8244628906,
          "ymax":54.9469413757,
          "confidence":0.5319843888,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        },
        {
          "xmin":40.3276748657,
          "ymin":61.7071838379,
          "xmax":792.4362182617,
          "ymax":220.5228271484,
          "confidence":0.8776857257,
          "class":8,
          "name":"table-with-no-lines"
        },
        {
          "xmin":19.0209159851,
          "ymin":254.4715881348,
          "xmax":817.498046875,
          "ymax":496.2465515137,
          "confidence":0.8490975499,
          "class":8,
          "name":"table-with-no-lines"
        },
        {
          "xmin":317.4003295898,
          "ymin":238.9741973877,
          "xmax":532.1016235352,
          "ymax":250.3171234131,
          "confidence":0.6407798529,
          "class":6,
          "name":"paragraph"
        }
      ]
```

And this is what the order should be

[objective order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9NiX.jpg)

Basic sorting it would not work to handle this problem, so i found that post, and wonder how it would be possible to do the same thing on Yolo output.

Thank you!

Comment: SO is not meant to code for you, but to help you specific problems. Try something and come back if you are stuck on a specific task.