# How to create image sequence?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

My problem is extracting the text from multiple columns of .PDF.
Common libs like `PyPDF2` didn't work.

The code below I made to try to read with `Pytesseract` but I was also unsuccessful because it is mixing the two columns.

Now my idea using this code as a base is to create a cutout in each column 1 and 2 and generate a new image by pasting column 1 and then columns 2 below, so I could read with `Pytesseract` or `AWS Textract` without problems.

how could i do this with `opencv`?

```
import fitz
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
SCANNED_FILE = "decreto_santos.pdf"

img = cv2.imread(SCANNED_FILE)
zoom_x = 2.0
zoom_y = 2.0
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom_x, zoom_y)

# I create an image for each page of the PDF and save.
doc = fitz.open(SCANNED_FILE)

print("Generated pages: ")
for page in doc:
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matriz=mat)
        png = 'output/' + SCANNED_FILE.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + 'page-%i.png' % page.number
        print(png)
        pix.save(png)


# Upload an image to crop
original_image = cv2.imread('output/decreto_santospage-1.png')


# Grayscale image
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
plt.imshow(gray_image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Result:
```

[image]

```
# Otsu thresholding
ret, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0,255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
plt.imshow(threshold_image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
# Result:
```

[image]

```
rectangular_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))

# Applying dilation on the threshold image
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(threshold_image, rectangular_kernel, iterations = 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
plt.imshow(dilated_image)
plt.show()
# Result:
```

[image]

```
# Finding contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)



# Creating a copy of the image
copied_image = original_image.copy()

with open("output/recognized-kernel-66-66.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("")
f.close()

mask = np.zeros(original_image.shape, np.uint8)
 
# Looping through the identified contours
# Then rectangular part is cropped and passed on to pytesseract
# pytesseract extracts the text inside each contours
# Extracted text is then written into a text file
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
     
    # Cropping the text block for giving input to OCR
    cropped = copied_image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
with open("output/recognized-kernel-66-66.txt", "a") as f:
        # Apply OCR on the cropped image
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped, lang='por', config='--oem 1 --psm 1')
        print(text)
        
    masked = cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
plt.imshow(masked, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[My base for this code was this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/read-a-multi-column-pdf-with-pytesseract-in-python-1d99015f887a)

Comment: You need to preprocess the image before throwing into OCR with the target to extract in the foreground in black and the background in white. Also I dont think OCR can extract the entire page at once, you may have to find contours, crop ROI and OCR each ROI individually

Comment: @nathancy The preprocessing is having a good result.
The OCR is able to read all the letters correctly too, the problem is the order in which it is reading, it is basically reading it line by line and this ends up mixing the contents of the first and second columns.
My biggest difficulty is to select and cut the first column and then the second column because that way it would be possible for me to play the second column below the first, thus making a single column. Did you understand?

Comment: Use [`imutils.sort_contours`](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7) with `top-to-down` or `left-to-right`

Comment: @wilian have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654302/how-can-i-sort-contours-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom

Comment: Find the center of the page. And sort contours on the left of the center first. Followed by those on the right