# How to find top_left, top_right, bottom_left, right coordinates in 2d mask where cell has specified value?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2D numpy array which is a mask from an image. Each cell has `0` or `1` value. So I would like to find top:left,right, bottom:left,right in an array where value is 1.

For example input array:

```
[00000]
[01110]
[01100]
[00000]
```

Expected output: `(1,1), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2)`

Comment: [00000]
    [01110]
    [01101]
    [00010]
what output do you expect for this input?

Comment: Do you have a problem with your solution?

Comment: numpy.where will return indices of your condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `np.argwhere` and `itertools.product`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def corners(np_array):
    ind = np.argwhere(np_array)
    res = []
    for f1, f2 in product([min,max], repeat=2):
        res.append(f1(ind[ind[:, 0] == f2(ind[:, 0])], key=lambda x:x[1]))
    return res
corners(arr)
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([2, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([2, 2], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Nice one, had completely forgotten about `itertools.product`!

Comment: hi Chris, do you have a more efficient way of answering this question? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630052/ordering-coordinates-from-top-left-to-bottom-right

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `numpy.amax` operation for finding max values in a multi_dimensional array. As below

```
def corners_v2(np_array):
    max_values = np.amax(np_array)
    result = np.where(np_array == np.amax(np_array))
    x1 = np.min(result[0])
    x2 = np.max(result[0])
    y1 = np.min(result[1])
    y2 = np.max(result[1])
    return x1, y1, x2, y2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xy=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
x,y=np.where(xy==1)
tl_i=np.argmin(x)
tl=[x[tl_i],y[tl_i]]
tr_i=np.argmax(y)
tr=[x[tr_i],y[tr_i]]
bl_i=np.argmax(x)
bl=[x[bl_i],y[bl_i]]
br_i=len(x)-1-np.argmax(np.flip(x))
br=[x[br_i],y[br_i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transpose` and `nonzero` from `numpy`, like:

```py
im=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]])

print(np.transpose(np.nonzero(im)))
```

yields:

```py
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

**Update:**
Still not perfect, but as long as the mask is *continuous* within its rows, you could evaluate `np.diff()` to get an idea where the `0->1` and `1->0` transitions are:

```py
leftedge=np.transpose(np.nonzero(np.diff(im,prepend=0)==1))
rightedge=np.transpose(np.nonzero(np.diff(im,append=0)==-1))

top_left     = leftedge[0]
bottom_left  = leftedge[-1]
bottom_right = rightedge[-1]
top_right    = rightedge[0]

pts=[list(x) for x in [top_left,top_right,bottom_left,bottom_right]]
```

yields: `[[1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2]]`

I'd suggest to use [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56151041/565489) instead.

Comment: This finds all elements that are equal to one, not the corners of the mask.